# How do I get Space info on objects above the space's ceiling?

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I'm a MEP engineer and I want to add space information on mechanical equipment, duct accessories and pipe accessories above the (room bounding) ceilings.

My first idea was to use BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter with an Outline with a modified `ClosedShell.GetBoundingBox().Max.Z` from the space and then use a `BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter` to catch my elements. This method works, but I will have trouble with accuracy above spaces which are note limited to six sides. This is because of the fact than Outline only takes to points. Now, I'm thinking I need to convert my spaces to a solid geometry and modify the Z-value and then use the `ElementIntersectsElementFilter`, but I am currently stuck figuring out which methods to use to modify my space geometry.

Maybe I need to use the [`GetGeometryObjectFromReference`](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/536b3d7a-ec8d-29f6-5957-751468c98dd0.htm), but I do not really understand how to use `Reference`. I've seen `get_Geometry` has been used [here](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/08/bottom-face-of-a-wall.html), but I need help how to use it. Specifically, this is the code I do not understand how to implement in python code:

```
foreach( GeometryObject obj in e.Objects )
  {
    Solid solid = obj as Solid;
    if( null != solid )
    {
      foreach( Face face in solid.Faces )
      {
        PlanarFace pf = face as PlanarFace;
        if( null != pf )
```

Any kick in the right direction is much appreciated!

Kyrre

Comment: You might want to use ReferenceIntersector. Here is an exemple, replace floor/roof by space : https://github.com/CyrilWaechter/pyRevitMEP/blob/master/pyRevitMEP.tab/Data.panel/ElevationUnder.pushbutton/script.py

Answer (score 2):

When I've done this before, sometimes I've used an easier approach. Identify the key point on the equipment, then drop down the z-value on that equipment point to a z-value just above the next Level down that has spaces on it, and then test that XYZ to determine which space encloses it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. I think the simplest might be to simply do this in two steps. First, use a bounding box or an outline or whatever quick filter fits your needs to reduce the number of potential candidate objects to a reasonable number within a rectangular area. In a second step, iterate through the candidate objects one by one an call the [Space. IsPointInSpace method](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/33c97031-a9ad-00d0-4d4a-42522201d2db.htm) on each of them to eliminate the ones lying outside an irregular space boundary.